# ¿Cómo puedo elimar un div pulsando un checbox?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código. Sin embargo, me falta una función bastante necesaria. Cuando se inserta una persona, aparece un checkbox que si es señalado y se pulsa el botón eliminar, dicho div se elimina. La función que se encarga de eliminar dichos div es delete1(). Lo eliminado ya está realizado, pero no se cómo puedo renombrar los id de los checbox para que se queden nuevamente en este orden check1, check2, check3, check4, etc. y que los label con el número, por ejemplo `<label id="1">1</label>` se vuelvan a renombrar de tal forma que queden como id 1, 2, 3 , 4. No se si me estoy explicando

```html
<script>
var paga1 = "false"
    var cantidad1 = "false"
    var num = 0
    var cantidad = []
    var paga = []
    var merienda = []
    var nombres = []
    var config2 = "mostrado"
    var inicio = 0
    var removidos 
    var iddelnum = 1
    var irsumando = 1
    
function delete1() {
 
 for (b = 0; b < num; b++) {
  var checkb2 = "check" + irsumando
  var valordelcheck = document.getElementById(checkb2);
  
   if(valordelcheck.checked) {
    var ppa = "persona" + irsumando
    var myobj = document.getElementById(ppa);
    myobj.remove();
   }
  irsumando = irsumando + 1
  }
  //Una vez que reccorriste todo para eliminar se puede volver a recorrer todo para renonmbrar los id
  let allPersonas = document.querySelectorAll('.persona');
  for(let i = 0 ; i < allPersonas.length ; i++){
   
    allPersonas[i].querySelector('label').innerText = i;
    allPersonas[i].querySelector('label').id = i;
    allPersonas[i].querySelector('input').id = 'check' + i;
    allPersonas[i].id = 'persona' + i;

  }
 setTimeout(function(){ 
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("persona").length;
  num = divs
  irsumando = 0
  num = num - 1
}, 1000);
 
}


    function insertar() {
     var Nombresocio = document.getElementById("nombresocio").value
     var nombremin = Nombresocio.toLowerCase();
     var Contenido = document.getElementById("addsocios").innerHTML
     var cantidadpagada = 0
     var merendo 
     var pago 
     var merienda2
     var paga2
     var cantidad2
     
     if(inicio == 0) {
      document.getElementById("barra").innerHTML = "<hr><p><input onclick='toggle(this)' type='checkbox' /> <button onclick='delete1()'>Eliminar</button></p><hr>"
      inicio = 1
     }
     
     if(Nombresocio == "" || Nombresocio == " " || Nombresocio == "  ") {
      return false;
     }
     
     var cadena = Nombresocio.toLowerCase().split(' ');
     for (var t = 0; t < cadena.length; t++) {
      cadena[t] = cadena[t].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cadena[t].substring(1);
     }
     Nombresocio = cadena.join(' ');

     
     if(paga1 == "false") {
      cantidadpagada = 0
      merendo = "No"
      pago = "No"
      merienda2 = "<label style='color:red'>No merienda</label>"
      paga2 = ""
      cantidad2 = ""
     } else if(paga1 == "active") {
      if(cantidad1 == "active") {
       cantidadpagada = Number(document.getElementById("cantidad").value);
       merendo = "Sí"
       pago = "Sí"
       merienda2 = "<label style='color:green'>Sí merienda</label>, "
       paga2 = "<label style='color:green'>Sí paga</label>, "
       cantidad2 = "<label style='color:green'>" + cantidadpagada + "cts</label>"
      } else if(cantidad1 = "false") {
       merendo = "Sí"
       pago = "No"
       cantidadpagada = 0
       merienda2 = "<label style='color:green'>Sí merienda</label>, "
       paga2 = "<label style='color:red'>No paga</label>"
       cantidad2 = ""
      }
     }

     paga.push(pago);
     cantidad.push(cantidadpagada);
     merienda.push(merendo);
     nombres.push(Nombresocio);
     
     
     
     num = num + 1
     var iddiv = "persona" + num
     var checkb = "check" + num
     var cam = "<div class='persona' id="+ iddiv +">"
     cam = cam + "<p><input class='hola' id="+ checkb +" type='checkbox' /> <b><label id="+ iddelnum +">"+ num +"</label>. "+ Nombresocio +":</b> "+ merienda2 + paga2 + cantidad2 +"</div>"
     iddelnum = iddelnum + 1
     Contenido = Contenido + cam
     document.getElementById("addsocios").innerHTML = Contenido
     document.getElementById("nombresocio").value = ""
     document.getElementById("repetirformulario").innerHTML = "<select  style='display:inline-block' id='merienda' onchange='addpaga()'><option>No merienda</option><option>Merienda</option></select> <select style='display:none;' id='paga' onchange='adddinero()'><option>No paga</option><option>Paga</option></select> <select id='cantidad' style='display:none;'><option>50</option><option>100</option></select>"
     paga1 = "false"
     cantidad1 = "false"
     return false;
    }

    function addpaga() {
     if(paga1 == "false") {
      if(cantidad1 == "active") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "inline-block"
       document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "inline-block"
       paga1 = "active"
      } else if(cantidad1 == "false") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "inline-block"
       paga1 = "active"
      }

     } else if (paga1 == "active") {
      if(cantidad1 == "active") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "none"
       document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "none"
       paga1 = "false"
      } else if(cantidad1 == "false") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "none"
       paga1 = "false"
      } 
     }
    }

    function adddinero() {
     if(cantidad1 == "false") {
      document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "inline-block"
      cantidad1 = "active"
     } else if(cantidad1 == "active") {
      document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "none"
      cantidad1 = "false"
     }
    }

    function toggle(source) {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.hola');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i] != source)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="todo">
     
       <form onsubmit="return insertar();">
       <input id="nombresocio" placeholder="&#128100;Nombre del socio..." required> 
       <div style="display:inline-block" id="repetirformulario">
        <select id="merienda" onchange="addpaga()">
         <option>No merienda</option>
         <option>Merienda</option>
        </select>
        <select style="display:none;" id="paga" onchange="adddinero()">
         <option>No paga</option>
         <option>Paga</option>
        </select>
        <select id="cantidad" style="display:none;">
         <option>50</option>
         <option>100</option>
        </select>
          </div>
       <input type="button" value="Insertar" onclick="insertar();"/> <input type="button" onclick="generar()" value="Generar" id="myBtn" />
      </form> 
     <div id="barra"></div>
     <div id="addsocios">
      
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como va, es muy simple lo que necesitas, algo bien simple para hacerlo es a ese div que creas para cada persona agregarle una clase, para que luego cuando elimines puedas seleccionar todos las  "personas" y renombrar lo que necesites renombrar con un FOR.

```js
 var paga1 = "false"
    var cantidad1 = "false"
    var num = 0
    var cantidad = []
    var paga = []
    var merienda = []
    var nombres = []
    var config2 = "mostrado"
    var inicio = 0
    var removidos 
    var iddelnum = 1

    function delete1() {
 let allPersonas = document.querySelectorAll('.persona');
 console.log(allPersonas);
 for (let b = 0; b < allPersonas.length ; b++) {
  let checkb2 = "check" + (b+1);
  console.log(checkb2);
  let valordelcheck = allPersonas[b].querySelector('#' + checkb2);
   if(valordelcheck.checked) {
    let ppa = "persona" + (b+1)
    let myobj = document.getElementById(ppa);
    myobj.remove();
   }
  }
  //Una vez que reccorriste todo para eliminar se puede volver a recorrer todo para renonmbrar los id
  allPersonas = document.querySelectorAll('.persona');

  for(let i = 0 ; i < allPersonas.length ; i++){
    //Accedemos a cada una de las personas que estan ahora
    let newId = i + 1;

    allPersonas[i].querySelector('label').innerText = newId;
    allPersonas[i].querySelector('label').id = newId;
    allPersonas[i].querySelector('input').id = 'check' + newId;
    allPersonas[i].id = 'persona' + newId;


  }
    }


    function insertar() {
     var Nombresocio = document.getElementById("nombresocio").value
     var nombremin = Nombresocio.toLowerCase();
     var Contenido = document.getElementById("addsocios").innerHTML
     var cantidadpagada = 0
     var merendo 
     var pago 
     var merienda2
     var paga2
     var cantidad2
     
     if(inicio == 0) {
      document.getElementById("barra").innerHTML = "<hr><p><input onclick='toggle(this)' type='checkbox' /> <button onclick='delete1()'>Eliminar</button></p><hr>"
      inicio = 1
     }
     
     if(Nombresocio == "" || Nombresocio == " " || Nombresocio == "  ") {
      return false;
     }
     
     var cadena = Nombresocio.toLowerCase().split(' ');
     for (var t = 0; t < cadena.length; t++) {
      cadena[t] = cadena[t].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cadena[t].substring(1);
     }
     Nombresocio = cadena.join(' ');

     
     if(paga1 == "false") {
      cantidadpagada = 0
      merendo = "No"
      pago = "No"
      merienda2 = "<label style='color:red'>No merienda</label>"
      paga2 = ""
      cantidad2 = ""
     } else if(paga1 == "active") {
      if(cantidad1 == "active") {
       cantidadpagada = Number(document.getElementById("cantidad").value);
       merendo = "Sí"
       pago = "Sí"
       merienda2 = "<label style='color:green'>Sí merienda</label>, "
       paga2 = "<label style='color:green'>Sí paga</label>, "
       cantidad2 = "<label style='color:green'>" + cantidadpagada + "cts</label>"
      } else if(cantidad1 = "false") {
       merendo = "Sí"
       pago = "No"
       cantidadpagada = 0
       merienda2 = "<label style='color:green'>Sí merienda</label>, "
       paga2 = "<label style='color:red'>No paga</label>"
       cantidad2 = ""
      }
     }

     paga.push(pago);
     cantidad.push(cantidadpagada);
     merienda.push(merendo);
     nombres.push(Nombresocio);
     
     
     
     num = num + 1
     var iddiv = "persona" + num
     var checkb = "check" + num
     var cam = "<div class='persona' id="+ iddiv +">"
     cam = cam + "<p><input class='hola' id="+ checkb +" type='checkbox' /> <b><label id="+ iddelnum +">"+ num +"</label>. "+ Nombresocio +":</b> "+ merienda2 + paga2 + cantidad2 +"</div>"
     iddelnum = iddelnum + 1
     Contenido = Contenido + cam
     document.getElementById("addsocios").innerHTML = Contenido
     document.getElementById("nombresocio").value = ""
     document.getElementById("repetirformulario").innerHTML = "<select  style='display:inline-block' id='merienda' onchange='addpaga()'><option>No merienda</option><option>Merienda</option></select> <select style='display:none;' id='paga' onchange='adddinero()'><option>No paga</option><option>Paga</option></select> <select id='cantidad' style='display:none;'><option>50</option><option>100</option></select>"
     paga1 = "false"
     cantidad1 = "false"
     return false;
    }

    function addpaga() {
     if(paga1 == "false") {
      if(cantidad1 == "active") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "inline-block"
       document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "inline-block"
       paga1 = "active"
      } else if(cantidad1 == "false") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "inline-block"
       paga1 = "active"
      }

     } else if (paga1 == "active") {
      if(cantidad1 == "active") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "none"
       document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "none"
       paga1 = "false"
      } else if(cantidad1 == "false") {
       document.getElementById("paga").style.display = "none"
       paga1 = "false"
      } 
     }
    }

    function adddinero() {
     if(cantidad1 == "false") {
      document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "inline-block"
      cantidad1 = "active"
     } else if(cantidad1 == "active") {
      document.getElementById("cantidad").style.display = "none"
      cantidad1 = "false"
     }
    }

    function toggle(source) {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.hola');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i] != source)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="todo">
         
           <form onsubmit="return insertar();">
           <input id="nombresocio" placeholder="?Nombre del socio..." required> 
           <div style="display:inline-block" id="repetirformulario">
            <select id="merienda" onchange="addpaga()">
             <option>No merienda</option>
             <option>Merienda</option>
            </select>
            <select style="display:none;" id="paga" onchange="adddinero()">
             <option>No paga</option>
             <option>Paga</option>
            </select>
            <select id="cantidad" style="display:none;">
             <option>50</option>
             <option>100</option>
            </select>
              </div>
           <input type="button" value="Insertar" onclick="insertar();"/> <input type="button" onclick="generar()" value="Generar" id="myBtn" />
          </form> 
         <div id="barra"></div>
         <div id="addsocios">
 
         </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Luego deberías hacer las validaciones necesarias para ver si las otras funciones siguen funcionando como deberían! Por el tema de los nombres

El truquito acá fue agregarle una clase a los DIV de persona para luego poder aplicarles un **querySelector** al mismo, esto va a encontrar el elemento buscado solo dentro de ese div.

EDIT: Ahora si funciona mas de 1 vez, el problema que tenias es esa variable NUM que la tenes definida globalmente. Es mucho mas practico recorrer un array(como el de personas) con el metodo .length que tiendem mucho menos al error ya que nos vas a tener nodos vacios a los cuales le apliques las funcion checked, el problema que te queda para resolver es cuando se eliminan todos las personas, la nueva persona arranca con el valor de la variable 'num', fijate de hacer esa funcionalidad un poco mas dinamica jugando con los querySelector y los metodos .length

Comment: Gracias Franklins, pero a la segunda vez que lo intento, ya no funciona. ¿Se puede solucionar eso también?

Comment: Ahi edite la respuesta para que funcione! Tenes que chequear muy bien el tema de esa variable "num" que tenes por ahi dando vueltas! Y un consejito se mucho mas descriptivo con el nombre de las variables, va a ser que tu codigo sea mucho mas legible, no importa si te quedan nombre muy largos como var nombreDeTodasLasPersonas. Es mucho mas debuggable